# Get rid of extra fold dashes in Vim folding

Tags: vim

I am using the script from [here](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim_dotfiles/blob/a1a106081884647922395fe4512aa8fcc887d64c/plugin/CustomFoldText.vim), and it seems setting the g:custom_foldtext_max_width variable cannot get rid of the extra "--" symbols in the end of the folded lines.

Is there any way to make the folded line not go beyond 80 characters ?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try this command.

```
   %!fold -sw80
```